# Getting Magento API from the Magento website

Tags: android, api, magento, payment-gateway

I want to get API of Magento cart that I deployed on and is live now. I want to get API so that I can make an Android app for my e-commerce website..!!

Answer (score 0):

Please read about Magento SOAP on their website

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html